# Select d3.js data element by attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a grid represented using d3.js and svg.
What I want to do is change the colour of a tile and all adjacent tiles when the  tile is clicked.
I am wondering the best way to select the tiles adjacent to the one clicked.
My code so far:

```
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    z = 20,
    x = w / z,
    y = h / z;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.range(x * y))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("transform", translate)
    .attr("position", pos)
    .attr("width", z)
    .attr("height", z)
    .attr("clicked", false)
    //.on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("click", click)
    .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
    .style("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")


function translate(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d % x) * z + "," + Math.floor(d / x) * z + ")";
}

function pos(d) {
  return [ (d % x) * z , Math.floor(d / x) * z ];
}

function click(d) {
  var currentColor = this.style.fill;
  var clickedYet = d3.select(this).attr("clicked");
  currentColor = currentColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ? "rgb(255, 0, 255)" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)";


  d3.select(this)
    .attr("clicked", true)
    .transition()
      .style("fill", currentColor);

}
```

What I was wondering, is whether is is possible to select tiles/ "rect" by the attribute position? Or if I should consider a completely different approach?

Comment: I would assign classes to each of the elements that encodes the position, i.e. `vertical-1` and `horizontal-5` or something like that. Then you can use the classes to select the correct elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks, might have to go for this, at the moment i'm just trying to learn how it all works, but my goal is to visualise a searching algorithm on the grid, such a a bfs, do you think this is a reasonable approach?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way *(selecting all the rectangle in the same row)*:

I have commented the code for better understanding of the algorithm.

```
function click(d) {
  var currentColor = this.style.fill;
  //this will give the data associated with the rectangle
  var clickeddata = d3.select(this).data();
 //this will give the row to be highlihted
  var row = parseInt(clickeddata/x);
  //current color calculation
  currentColor = currentColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ? "rgb(255, 0, 255)" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
  //iterate through all the rectangle
  d3.selectAll("rect")[0].forEach(function(r){
    //all rectangle with same row 
    if(parseInt(d3.select(r).data()/x) == row){
      //make it color as it is in the same row
      d3.select(r)
        .attr("clicked", true)
        .transition()
          .style("fill", currentColor);     
    }
  });
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7nc35err/).